# Fish Pipeline Status

Tags: shell, status, pipeline, fish

In fish:

```
if false | true | true
  echo "Fish thinks OK because of last status"
else
  # But I...
  echo "Need the entire pipeline to be true"
end
```

Bash has $PIPESTATUS.
How does one test the integrity of a pipeline in Fish?

To clarify...
I'm using true and false in the example pipeline as an example
of a pipeline which last component succeeds.
It's not meant to be a boolean statement.
Normally, if any component of a pipeline fails,
one would consider the pipeline as having failed.

Comment: I think this is not possible at the moment, see: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/805

Comment: so `false | true ...` is a place holder for a set of pipe-lined commands? Or does fish suport logical and/or's i.e. `&& , || `, and is your goal to pass information between multiple processes, or just to keep a cmd from running if a previous command has failed? Good luck.

Comment: Fish supports logical and/or through `and`, `or`. But it doesn't support pipes at the moment. So if the commands didn't pipe you could write `if false; and true; and true`. If they are made to work with pipes, it would be: `if false | and true | and true`

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible (other than ugly workarounds where you construct the pipe manually via `set var (echo $initialinput | firstcommand); and set var (echo $var | secondcommand); and`...j

This is tracked as [fish bug #2039](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2039).